# How to get current location latitude and longitude?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to get user current location.Here is my code:

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocation{
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

        return coordinate;
}
```

and this is where i call it in viewDidLoad

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self getLocation];
double latitude = coordinate.latitude;
double longitude = coordinate.longitude;
```

and it return 0.000000 for both latitude and longitude.
Any help please! I'm using Xcode 8 and running on My real iPhone 6s not Emulator.

Comment: where is ur delegate methds

Comment: Go through this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
    {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
       locationManager.delegate = self;
       locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
       locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

       if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
                        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

       [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
     {
        CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
        NSLog(@"lat%f - lon%f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
    }
```

Comment: your answer is fine, but in future dont encourage the duplicate answers

Comment: will this code works for iO8 below and iOS 10? @Nidhi Patel

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper iOS 10 it's work.

Comment: Thanks! @NidhiPatel

Comment: did u worked on APNS server side configuration? @NidhiPatel